# Laravel - Sesiones en base de datos

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-7

tengo un proyecto **laravel** donde uso **passport**, estava usando como driver fichero , pero he decidido cambiarlo a base de datos, para ello he modificado lo siguiente en mi fichero .env

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=9999999999
```

Luego en el archivo **config/session.php**

```
   'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
```

Luego he ejecutado estos comandos

```
 php artisan session:table && composer dump-autoload && php artisan migrate
```

Ahora entro a mi aplicación y me loggeo con el usuario y contraseña y veo que en la tabla sessions se genera un registro, por lo que entiendo que mi sesión ya esta funcionando por base de datos y no por ficheros.

[image: lar]

El problema lo tengo cuando accedo a una ruta que la tengo en el middleware "api"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Fichero de rutas**

```
    Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['web','auth']
], function () {

    Route::get('/forms/{user_id}/list','Api\CarController@list');

});
```

Gracias por adelantado